# jQuery css() function changing 'a' property not 'a:hover' property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic-css

I'm having a bit of trouble with the jQuery `css()` function at the moment. It is changing the css value of the anchor element's `border-top-color` instead of just the anchor element's `border-top-color` when hovered. Below is my code.

```
$("#header #headerlist li a:hover").css("border-top-color","rgb(225, 149, 79)");
```

Why does it change the `#header #headerlist li a` border-top-color and the `#header #headerlist li a:hover` properties rather than just the `#header #headerlist li a:hover` property?

Comment: Exactly what you are looking for is not possible, please see here more details: (jQuery Bug tracker: ACCESS :HOVER CSS PROPERTIES OF AN ELEMENT VIA JQUERY: bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4434). Therefore workarounds provided in other answers should be used instead.

Answer (score 20):

The reason your example doesn't work is because the selector has no way of detecting  :hover since that's a pure CSS thing.  Instead you might try using the actual [jquery hover method](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover):

```
$("#header #headerlist li a").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).css("border-top-color", "#FF0000");
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).css("border-top-color", "#000000");
  }
);
```

Alternatively, you could also use the addclass method as well:

```
$("#header #headerlist li a").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass('hover-highlight');
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass('hover-highlight');
  }
);
```

This could be further simplified to:

```
$("#header #headerlist li a").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover-highlight');
});
```

Comment: toggleClass('hover-highlight');  ;)

Answer (score 12):

I don't know exactly why, but this type of changes are better done in CSS, so I'd suggest that, if you really need to change this through JS, create a CSS class, then change that in JS.

#### CSS

```
#header #headerlist li a.fancy-border:hover{
  border-top-color: rgb(225, 149, 79);
}
```

#### JS

```
$("#header #headerlist li a").addClass("fancy-border");
```

That way you can better separate functionality from presentation.

Comment: Agreed.  I usually use the add/remove class approach since it keeps all the styles in one place.  You don't have to edit javascript to change the hover colours, for example.

Comment: Better because you're minimising presentational data in your behavioural layer.

Comment: #header is a bit excessive too in that selector, imho

Comment: @Chad While ID's are supposed to be unique in each page, you might have server-side includes that put certain IDs as children of different elements depending on the section of the site you're seeing, so chaining IDs might be useful indeed.

Comment: Thankyou for everyone's answers, I think I'm going create a new class and use the jQuery addClass method.

Thankyou all.

Comment: If this answer is the one for your question, then please mark as answered by clicking on the thick at the left so others with the same problem know how to solve it ;)

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because the `:hover` bit doesn't actually give the selector any information about an element.

`a:hover` in CSS matches on the same exact elements as  `a`, it's just defining a different set of properties for when the user is hovering over those elements.

The jQuery selector is designed to find (select) elements, not to style them.

The `css()` method simply sets an inline style on the elements that are selected, it does **not** add or change any actual CSS declarations.

As other have mentioned, you can use the `hover()` event to get the same behavior.  Although, adding a class on the fly is probably better, as another answerer described.

However, if you don't need to make it change on-the-fly, I recommend using plain old CSS since it is faster and does not require a user to have javascript enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This code is broken since 1.9

```
if($('...').is(':hover')){
  $(this).css('set','your styles here')
}
```

use this instead

```
var class = '...';
if($(class+':hover').length>0){
  $(class).css('set','your styles here');
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. JavaScript console says: `unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover`

Comment: broken since jquery 1.9

Answer (score 0):

add !important to the hover css to avoid the style is overrided.
for example:

```js
test:hover {
    border: 1.5px solid white !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```