# Changing 'a' property using jquery css() function also change a:hover,a:acive,a:focus properties

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I am initially styling links(also different states) using css and then i am changing css properties for a tag using jquery css() function. The problem is- the css() function seems to effect not only a but also all it states.
That mean writing 'a' corresponds to all states of 'a'. So we need to write something kind of a:link and change only 'a:link' not 'a'.

> How to write this using jquery.

Code what I am doing:
**CSS:**

```
#topics_nav a {
    color:#000; 
}
#topics_nav a:visited{
    color:#c00;
}
#topics_nav a:hover,a:active,a:focus{
    color:#FFF;
}
```

**jquery:**

```
$("document").ready(function(e) {
    $('#topics_nav a').css('color','#300');
});
```

This jQuery changes color of all states to `#300`.

*I don't want to change only the link state and don't want to modify any other state.* The following solution give a method to only affect hover(or any other) state but is there any other method instead of adding/deleting classes.

There is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/837779/742173) to define some desired classes(classes like `class1:hover`) and instead of changing css we can change class.
But what about `:link`?

Comment: This is because JavaScript sets the in-line styles of an element (`style="color: #f00;"`), which are immediately more specific than the rules defined using pseudo-classes (`:hover`, `:active`, etc). Why not take the same approach as that to which you link, and simply add a class to the default state of the `a` elements? (Assuming that you can't simply edit the CSS, which would be far more reliable and far less complex.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#topics_nav a {
    color:#000; 
}
#topics_nav a:visited{
    color:#c00;
}
#topics_nav a:hover,a:active,a:focus{
    color:#FFF;
}
.myclass:hover {
    color: #300;
}


$("document").ready(function() {
    $('#topics_nav a').addClass('myclass');
});
```

I think this is a better way to do it. Let CSS style the elements like this.

Comment: I did this but I got hover color #fff not #300 after the page load. I checked the final html(using inspect element) and I found that 'myclass' class is added to the 'a' tags. But the hover color didn't changed.

Comment: oh, you may have to set !important in `.myclass:hover` because styling on ID is higher than styling on classes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because your code is incorrect?

#### original code

```
$('#topics_nav' a).css('color','#300');
```

#### correct code

```
$('#topics_nav a').css('color','#300');
```

Answer (score -1):

use this code. It may help you

```
$("document").ready(function(e) {
       $('#topics_nav a').hover(function(){
       $(this).css('color','#300');
  });
});
```