# Setting css styles using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, stylesheet

I need to set the css styles to the following elements as follows using jQuery

```
#hdr-nav-wrapper ul li:hover a{ 
    background-color:#0294ca;
}

 #hdr-nav-wrapper ul a:hover{ 
   background-color:#00aeff;
}
```

Except that the actual color will have to be dynamic based on whatever the background color of a div with id of "TestDiv". This site has a theme engine where users can change colors using a color theme palette. I am appending a nav bar to the top of the site but I want to have the background of the nav bar as the same as whatever "TestDiv" currently has.

How do I convert the above css to jQuery with that dynamic logic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery css() function changing 'a' property not 'a:hover' property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837741/jquery-css-function-changing-a-property-not-ahover-property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/). To make the swapping of the background color easier, wrap your `<a>` tag in a "display-block" element that can match the dimensions of the `<li>`. You will only need to add/remove background color on the new wrapper element (otherwise, you would have to save the old background color in a state to revert back to on mouseout)..

[Here is a demo in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GwbPj/).

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><div><a>test</a></div></li>
    <li><div><a>test</a></div></li>
</ul>
<div id="TestDiv" style="background-color:blue;">&nbsp;</div>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('ul li').hover(function() { 
    var $el = $(this).find('div');
    if($el.length > 0) {
        $el.css('background-color', $('#TestDiv').css('background-color'));
    }
}, function() {
    var $el = $(this).find('div');
    if($el.length > 0)
        $el.css('background-color','');
});
```

Comment: I may have had a slightly different idea of what you want to achieve. Are you sure you want to change the `<a>` background and not the `<li>`?

Comment: it was actually <li>. Thanks for your help!